# Python - Comparing two lists accounting for draws

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, `a` and `b`.

The two lists have 5 values e.g:

`a = [1,2,3,4,5]`
`b = [2,3,4,5,6]`

I need a function to compare the two so that if `sum(a) < sum(b)`, `b` is the winner, and if `sum(a) > sum(b)`, `a` is the winner.

If `sum(a) == sum(b)`:

The list the highest number in the first position will win

In the event of a second tie, the list the highest number in the second position will win

In the event of further ties, third, fourth and fifth positions will be compared.

In the event of a complete draw, return none.

I have had a go at this but my solution is very long and complex - I'm wondering if there is an easier way to solve this problem.

Comment: Is this an assignment?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: If you already have a working solution and would like some tips on how to improve it, you should ask this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (and post your code there).

Answer (score 3):

You just have to convert what you told to a program, like this

```
a, b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
total_a, total_b = sum(a), sum(b)
if total_a < total_b:
    print("B is bigger")
elif total_b < total_a:
    print("A is bigger")
else:
    for first, second in zip(a, b):
        if first > second:
            print("A is bigger")
            break
        elif second > first:
            print("B is bigger")
            break
    else:
        print("Draw")
```